# Need help understanding spring boot logs related to thread locks

Tags: java, heap-memory

A monolithic java spring application takes about 30 min to load in websphere. I am not familiar with the app. It does initially loads some of the db tables data to in memory for caching. we are in the process of converting to spring boot app and deploying to cloud foundry. We will be addressing the loading of the tables at startup. I gave the same -Xms and -Xmx memory requirements as in websphere.
I would like to know
a) why it is not crashing in websphere unlike cloud foundry although it takes 30 min. Is it something to do with sequential vs parallel processes. I see lot of timed_lock and locked messages in the log.
b) How can I read these logs and correlate to the code
c) anything in the springboot app for sequential rather than parallely retrieving from db tables. What is better process for caching  db data in memory

Below is a sample of the logs being spewed when we deploy to cloud foundry and the app crashes

```
er.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4907af0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4907af0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1095)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:477)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4907a40> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.578-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4907a40> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4907a40> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4958620> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4958620> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4958620> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4956c20> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4926508> (a java.lang.Object)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] - locked <0x00000006b4907d10> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054ba5000 nid=0x78 runnable
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054ba6800 nid=0x79 runnable
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054baa000 nid=0x7b runnable
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054bac000 nid=0x7c runnable
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054bae000 nid=0x7d runnable
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054bb1800 nid=0x7f runnable
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "GC task thread#10 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054bb3000 nid=0x80 runnable
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "GC task thread#11 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054bb5000 nid=0x81 runnable
2023-01-27T12:12:06.580-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] "VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6054905000 nid=0xc3 waiting on condition
2023-01-27T12:12:06.772-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/1] [OUT] [CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol INFO Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2023-01-27T12:12:06.824-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/1] [OUT] [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig INFO Deploying web application directory [/home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
2023-01-27T12:12:06.992-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] JNI global references: 6134825
2023-01-27T12:12:06.992-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] PSYoungGen total 1608704K, used 41812K [0x0000000789d80000, 0x00000007f4800000, 0x00000007f4800000)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.992-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] eden space 1483264K, 2% used [0x0000000789d80000,0x000000078c655158,0x00000007e4600000)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.992-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] to space 130560K, 0% used [0x00000007ec880000,0x00000007ec880000,0x00000007f4800000)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.993-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ParOldGen total 2785280K, used 276955K [0x00000006b4800000, 0x000000075e800000, 0x0000000789d80000)
2023-01-27T12:12:06.993-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] class space used 23934K, capacity 25150K, committed 25216K, reserved 1048576K
2023-01-27T12:12:11.570-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] jvmkill killing current process
```

Comment: It isn't totally clear what the question is. These logs look like part of a thread dump that is presumably generated when the application is killed. All of the lines shown are normal to see when Tomcat starts up and is initialising a web app. Cloud Foundry is most likely killing your application because of the slow startup time. See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-tips.html#slow-start

Comment: If you're looking for information on how to interpret the thread dump, these articles might be helpful https://dzone.com/articles/how-analyze-java-thread-dumps https://www.baeldung.com/java-analyze-thread-dumps. If you'd like more direct help interpreting a thread dump from the Stack Overflow community, you'll need to include the whole thing in the question, or at least the relevant parts of the trace that include your application classes.

Comment: The app is loading lot of relational tables data in memory which doesn't change  much at start up time so it is running lots of spring boot batch jobs in the background. Is there better way to cache the data in memory during startup

Comment: Maybe it could read the data as it’s needed rather than all at once during start up.